# Meteor: Added Meta Tags but Do Not Render in OpenGraph or Search

Tags: meteor, metadata, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I recently installed Kadira's DocHead package and took the necessary steps from the documentation to implement it into my app.

However, even with the meta tags appearing correctly, Open Graph and Search Engines don't see my Meta Tags.

Am I missing in my app to allow search and OG to crawl the app correctly?

I'm thinking of using PhantomJS or the Spiderable package to help with this. Any advice?

Comment: I'm having the same issue here and I haven't found a good solution yet. Anyone have a good way to do this?

Comment: Any updates on this?